# Creating raster calculation function using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I'm using QGIS and working with satelite images, I want to operate over bands for many different dates so when I enter in raster calculation I have to write the operation for every pair of bands.

Is there a way to create a function that I can call to input 2 bands and get the result?